# Can someone please explain me the imperative command of creating a job in Kubernates

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-eks

I am preparing for the CKAD Exam, and hence for speed, I am learning the imperative commands.  For creating a job the command is

```
kubectl create job NAME --image=image [--from=cronjob/name] -- [COMMAND] [args...]
```

Can someone give me an example on how to use the [COMMAND] and [args...] part here?

Comment: What do you want the Job to do?  Compare to similar arguments in `docker run`, for example, or just typing a command and its arguments into your local shell.

Comment: I just want an example on how to use the COMMAND field.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a Docker image that runs a Python script which takes two arguments. The Python script calculates the sum of two numbers and prints the result. The Docker image is tagged as `my-python-app:latest`.

You can create a Job to run this Python script using the following `kubectl` command:

```
kubectl create job calculate-sum --image=my-python-app:latest -- python calculate.py 5 7
```

In this example:

`calculate-sum` is the name of the Job.

`--image=my-python-app:latest` specifies the container image to use.

`-- python calculate.py 5 7` is the **command and arguments** to be passed to the container. Here, **python is the command to run**, and **calculate.py 5 7** are the arguments passed to the script.

The Job will create a pod that runs the specified command (python calculate.py 5 7), and the pod will terminate after completing the task. The Job controller will ensure that the desired number of completions (pods) are achieved, and it will handle the cleanup of resources after the Job is done.